# Product Flat Data unable to Re-index Even Trauncate catalog_product_flat_*

Tags: magento-1.7, reindex

Product Flat Data Unable to Reindex.

I am getting in some post that truncate catalog_product_flat_*. But i dont want to truncate all table of it.

I Truncate first three but not able to reindex.

Why we need to truncate all table ? Is there any reason ?

So if any other solution.Which can able to solve my problem.

Comment: can you check the exception.log file and see what the error is and post i here

Comment: THanks for quick response solution give here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/magento-1-7-cannot-reindex-product-flat-data/1544?noredirect=1#1544